# Stopping a service from multiple instances of the same service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am making an alarm clock app. I start a service by using intent.

```
    public void Start(View view) {
    hr = timePick.getCurrentHour();
    min = timePick.getCurrentMinute();
    service = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("HOUR", hr);
    bundle.putInt("MIN", min);
    service.putExtras(bundle);
    startService(service);

}
```

I stop the service by

```
    public void Stop(View view) {
    hr = timePick.getCurrentHour();
    min = timePick.getCurrentMinute();
    Intent myAlarm = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);
    Intent myService = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("HOUR", hr);
    bundle.putInt("MIN", min);
    myService.putExtras(bundle);
    myAlarm.putExtras(bundle);
    stopService(myAlarm);
    stopService(myService);
}
```

I may have multiple instances of the service running. However when I try to stop a single instance of the service by passing the hour and minute, all the instances of the service are stopped. I have used alarmmanager inside the service MyService. MyAlarm creates the notification.

eg. I have set alarm of 11.30 and 11.40. I wish to delete alarm for 11.40. So I press the stop button. But both the alarms get cancelled

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no such thing as running multiple instances of the same service, calling`startService(intent)` does not start another instance of the service it just calls `onStartCommand` again

from the docs

`Multiple requests to start the service result in multiple corresponding calls to the service's onStartCommand(). However, only one request to stop the service (with stopSelf() or stopService()) is required to stop it.`

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html